# How do I read a zip(which in fact is in bytes form) without creating a temporary copy?

Tags: django, python-3.x, file-upload, django-views, django-file-upload

I am uploading a zip(which further contains pdf files to be read) as `multipart/form-data` .

I am handling the upload as below:

```
file = request.FILES["zipfile"].read() #gives a byte object
bytes_io = io.BytesIO(file) # gives a IO stream object
```

What I intend to do is to read the pdf files inside the zip, but I am stuck as to how to proceed from here. I am confused, what do I do with either the bytes object from the request or the IO object after conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer just after asking the question.

Simply use the zipfile package as below:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
file = request.FILES["zipfile"].read()
bytes_io = io.BytesIO(file)
zipfile = ZipFile(bytes_io, 'r')
```

And then refer the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) for further operations on the zip file.
Hope it helps!